# Infinity loop in io.popen function in lua

Tags: lua, popen, openwrt

I want to execute following code infinitely.
However, if two devices are connected, the infinity loop is freeze at second scanning section(The second scanning section means that infinity loop begins second time and scan command is executed). Why this problem appears?

```
while true do
print("Hi")
s = io.popen("iw wlan0 scan")
s:close()
print("Done")

dis = io.popen("iw wlan0 disconnect")
dis:close()

c = io.popen("iw wlan0 connect Name")
c:close()
print("Goes to Scan")
end
```

Also, If I type commands in command line by hand(scan -> disconnect -> connect -> scan), then scan print result is repeat from 5 to 6 times automatically at second scanning. (When I execute scan command, the printed result is SYNC - End of SCAN, restore to 20MHz channel 32, Total BSS[02] bImprovedScan ............. Resume for bImprovedScan, SCAN_PENDING ............... and this printed text is repeat from 5 to 6 times). Is this situation is related to this problem?

Comment: what is "the second scanning section"? what's the printed output? what do you mean with stopped? does it freeze or abort with an error or what?

Comment: This is the printed output when scan command is executed. SYNC - End of SCAN, restore to 20MHz channel 32, Total BSS[02].

Comment: Stop means freeze. The second scanning section means that infinity loop begins second time and scan command is executed.

Comment: add this information to your quesiton... please read [ask]

Comment: Thanks. I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the `iw` command does, but using a pipe without reading anything from it and closing it immediately after opening it opens the possibility that the program never executes.

I suggest using `os.execute` instead of `io.popen`:

```
while true do
   print("Hi")
   os.execute("iw wlan0 scan; iw wlan0 disconnect; iw wlan0 connect Name")
   print("Goes to Scan")
end
```

Comment: Thank you it works when I give an interrupt by ctrl+c only in the first time. Could you teach me about this problem?

Comment: What does `s:close()` actually do?  Does it terminate the running process?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, no, but I thought it could. The man page for `pclose`
 says: "The pclose() function waits for the associated process to terminate".

Comment: @lhf - Does it try to terminate the process (by sending a signal) or does it wait passively?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, `s:close` simply calls `pclose`.